# Limit/offset output of Matrix field by 50%

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to limit and offset the output of a Matrix field by 50%? I wanted to split the data across two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have used, some math and the [`slice`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) filter.

```
{% set midIndex = ((entry.myMatrixField|length) / 2)|round - 1 %}

{% set blocksA = entry.myMatrixField|slice(0, midIndex) %}
{% set blocksB = entry.myMatrixField|slice(midIndex, null) %}
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to round up rather than down, the method in the argument is 'ceil'. So it would then be: round(0, 'ceil') ie https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/round.html